# リストをもとに総当たりさせて、経度緯度から距離を求めるコード

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで緯度経度をインプットしたときに、複数の2地点間距離を求めるコードを作成しています。
公式をもとに距離を求める関数は作成できたのですが、今のコードだと各地点の緯度経度を都度インプットしてそれぞれ距離を出さないといけないので、地点数が増えたときに膨大な手間がかかります。

ですので添付画像のようなリストをインポートして、経度緯度情報をもとに総当たりで2地点間距離を出せるようにしたいのですが、どのような書き方をすれば良いかご教示お願いできませんでしょうか。

コードは以下

```
#モジュールimport
from math import sin, cos, acos, radians

#地球の半径を6371kmとする
earth_rad = 6371

##関数定義
def latlng_to_xyz(lat, lng):
    rlat, rlng = radians(lat), radians(lng)
    coslat = cos(rlat)
    return coslat*cos(rlng), coslat*sin(rlng), sin(rlat)

def dist_on_sphere(pos0, pos1, radius=earth_rad):
    xyz0, xyz1 = latlng_to_xyz(*pos0), latlng_to_xyz(*pos1)
    return acos(sum(x * y for x, y in zip(xyz0, xyz1)))*radius

Osaka = 34.702113, 135.494807
Tokyo = 35.681541, 139.767103
London = 51.476853, 0.0

print(dist_on_sphere(Osaka, Tokyo)) # 403.63km
print(dist_on_sphere(London, Tokyo)) # 9571.22km
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「2地点間の距離を求める」部分は既に出来ているのであれば、ここでは「リストをインポートする方法」や「総当たりする方法」などに焦点を絞った書き方をした方がより良い回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！そうします！

Answer (score 1):

リストが意図している形式かわかりませんが、サンプルを提示しますね。

```
store_list = [
    [0, "札幌店",   "北海道", 43.062083, 141.354389],
    [1, "仙台店",   "宮城県", 38.268056, 140.869722],
    [2, "東京店",   "東京都", 35.689472, 139.691750],
    [3, "名古屋店", "愛知県", 35.181389, 136.906389],
    [4, "大阪店",   "大阪府", 34.693750, 135.502111]
]

def print_distance_list(lst):
    store, lat, lon = 1, 3, 4
    for i, lhs in enumerate(lst):
        for rhs in lst[i+1:]:
            dist = dist_on_sphere((lhs[lat], lhs[lon]), (rhs[lat], rhs[lon]))
            print(lhs[store], rhs[store], f'{dist:.2f}', 'km')

print_distance_list(store_list)
```